# Rails custom validation (reusable macro-style)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

Writing a Rails app.  I'd like to make a few more commonly used validations available across my models.  I understand how to do the built in validations, and how to write my own custom methods.  However, I find that I'm using the same validations in a few places and it feels awkward to be using mixins on the different classes.

Here's an example:  I have an object with prop1 and prop2.  Either is valid, but it is not valid to set both.  **Right now, I have something like**

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessor :prop1, :prop2
  validate :prop1_prop2_mutex

  def prop1_prop2_mutex 
     errors.add(:base, "Can not set prop1 and prop2") if prop1 && prop2
  end 
end
```

**What I'd really like to have is something like**

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessor :prop1, :prop2
  validate_mutex :prop1, :prop2
end
```

and then somewhere else I'm guessing I'd need something like

```
  def validate_mutex(property1, property2)
    rrors.add(:base, "Can not set prop1 and prop2") if self.send(property1) && self.send(property2)
  end
```

That might not be that close.

**So, how can I build in a new reusable validation method?

Or is there a better way to approach this problem?**

Please be general.  I have a few instances of this problem in different forms.  Though I would appreciate a super-simple, built in solution to this example, I have more complex validations that I'd like to apply the solution to.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [custom validators](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validator) API to do things like:

```
validate :mutex => :prop1
```